# Generate email once order is changed to filled in netsuite

Tags: workflow, netsuite

Once someone clicks on the fulfill button on the `Sales Order` I want it to send an email to someone.How can make this occur in `Netsuite`?

Comment: you mean after fulfilment is created from order using fulfilment button or fulfilment tab itself is clicked?

Comment: How to do this depends a great deal on how your Netsuite account is configured. Do you use Item Fulfillments? Are you using Pick/Pack/Ship?

Comment: Your question is phrased like you want to send an email when the button is clicked. That sounds like an internal notice. Do you mean you want to send an email when an order is shipped?

Comment: That is correct when the fulfillment button is clicked.  I want it to send an email or alert to a certain person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom workflow on sales order and configure the worflow to send email to the specific email id. The email id can be either custom one / a field value from the sales order record (ex. customer, salesperson etc.,)

The condition for the workflow will be

```
OldRecord.Status!="Pending Fulfillment" && NewRecord.Status!="Pending Fulfillment"
```

Thanks
Frederick D

Comment: Yes.. Use visual builder that is easiest way and the trigger should be in after submit event.

Comment: @fbarriga -- See the below link attached image for the visual builder. http://s22.postimg.org/mdefly781/Capture.png

Answer (score 2):

you can write a user event on Item Fulfillment record type and send email using `nlapiSendEmail()`

You may want to put a check in script if `type == 'create'` to avoid sending email on other record operation.

Comment: Hi prasun, thank for your answer.  How do I do your above task? Through suite script?  Can you guide me?

Comment: yes, through suitescript , specifically user event script, see help for a sample user event script